# Laravel 5 - cant get records

Tags: laravel-5

I can not get any records by using

```
return Offer::all();
```

although I see them if using

```
return DB::select('select * from offers where id = ?', array(1));
```

I get following error:

```
FatalErrorException in OffersController.php line 21:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Offer' not found
```

Both commands were run from OffersController. I also have model file

```
<?php namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Offer extends Model {

protected $fillable = array('title', 'done');
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I think I will use both 'DB' and 'Eloquent' in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following at the top of your OffersController

```
use Offer;
```

or perhaps

```
use App\Offer;
```

Comment: retrograde thank you very much, "use App\Offer;" works just fine.